# Use firebase storage with embedded native module in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have a react-native iOS app with Firebase and an embedded custom native module.

I want to use firebase storage to upload data to a bucket from both the native module and the react native part. How should I handle it without any issues?